# Registering the same type in a collection with Castle.Windsor gives exception

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to do DI with Castle.Windsor to components which are sitting in a List.

I have three types of classes (Boats, in this case), which all inherit from one interface (IBoat), and I generate 10 instances of these types randomly. When it adds different types, everything is fine, but when it comes to add the same type which already present in the collection, it gives the following error:

```
Component MarinaTest.SailBoat could not be registered. 
There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing 
component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.
```

The parent class with the collection inside it looks as following:

```
public class BoatsAtSea
{
    public List<IBoat> BoatsList { get; set; } 
    public BoatsAtSea(List<IBoat> boatsAtSea)
    {
        BoatsList = boatsAtSea;
    }
}
```

And the code of Castle I'm using:

```
Type[] types = {typeof(SailBoat), typeof(FisherBoat), typeof(YachtBoat)};


        var basContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        basContainer.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(basContainer.Kernel));
        basContainer.Register(Component.For<BoatsAtSea>());

        // Generate 10 random boats
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            basContainer.Register(Component.For<IBoat>().LifestyleTransient().ImplementedBy(types[new Random().Next(3)])
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("Name", "BT"+ i)));
        }

        BoatsAtSea boats = basContainer.Resolve<BoatsAtSea>();
```

I tried several options, but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show BoatAtSea class?

Comment: I did show it. It's just a short class which contains one collection of type <IBoat> and a ctor which accepts the collection. Look again please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register the implementations once:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                          .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                          .BasedOn<IBoat>()
                          .WithService.FromInterface()
                          .LifestyleTransient());
```

Then create a method for getting a random `IBoat` implementation:

```
private IEnumerable<IBoat> GetRandomBoatImplementation(IKernel container, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return container.ResolveAll<IBoat>()
                              .OrderBy(item => Guid.NewGuid())
                              .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Use this method to create the list. This makes ListResolver redundant because we are registering the type ourselves:

```
container.Register(Component.For<List<IBoat>>()
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(input => GetRandomBoatImplementation(input, 10).ToList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register explicitly same component(type) more than once.

According to to your code, the for loop leads to register same type(picked from you types array) more than once

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you Name your components using Named:

```
basContainer.Register(Component.For<IBoat>()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    .ImplementedBy(types[new Random().Next(3)])
    .Named("BT"+i)
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("Name", "BT"+ i)));
```

Also you have to change:

```
BoatsAtSea(List<IBoat> boatsAtSea)
```

to:

```
BoatsAtSea(IList<IBoat> boatsAtSea)
```

Kind regards,

Marwijn.